# System setting to stop WiFi from dropping connection?

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, kernel-parameters

My WiFi connection is frequently dropping.  Are there any system settings to help with the problem?

Comment: In my experience, that is due to weak WiFi signal. Move the machine, move the access point, see if something in between interferes and can be moved, ...

Comment: @vonbrand Increasing `mac80211` module parameters relating to disconnection has fixed the problem for me without having to move anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic way to try to fix things is to increase the `mac80211` kernel module parameters having to do with disconnections.  From `modinfo -p mac80211`:

> **max_nullfunc_tries**:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
>   **max_probe_tries**:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
>   **beacon_loss_count**:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
>   **probe_wait_ms**:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)

You can go to the directory `/sys/module/mac80211/parameters` and do `cat [parameter]` to see the current value of a parameter and (as root) do `echo [value] > [parameter]` to (non-persistently) set a parameter to a particular value.

To persistently/permanently set the parameters you can create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` like this:

```
options mac80211 max_nullfunc_tries=16
options mac80211 max_probe_tries=20
options mac80211 beacon_loss_count=28
```